# initwithstyle:reuseIdentifier: not called

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm creating my own custom `UITableViewCell` to use as the backend of a prototype cell. In my class I override the `initwithstyle:reuseIdentifier:` method to do some custom initialization, but my initializer is not called. I have a break point on the first line inside of it, as well as a break point on `dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier:`. The `dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier:` method is called, and it returns a initilized cell, but the break point in `initwithstyle:reuseIdentifier:` is not reached. Any help would be great.

Comment: Show us the code of your `UITableViewDataSource` where it's creating and returning cells please.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I'm not using storyboard, I'm creating it programmatically. Anyone know why the initWithStyle doesn't get called then?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If your cell is being created from a storyboard prototype (which you have declared as the custom class in IB) then it won't be created with `initWithStyle...` but `initWithCoder:` instead, like any other object loaded from a nib. If you have any setup code, it should be in there or in `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Is there somewhere in the docs that states initWithCoder is always used when loading from a nib? Your answer helped, but I'd like to read the relevant docs in case there's something else I've been missing.

Comment: Good question! Closest I can find is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html), under "Initializing View Instances Created in Interface Builder"

Comment: Hmm interesting, they suggest using awakeFromNib to do any initial setup. So does initWithCoder definitely get called every time?

Comment: Yes. AwakeFromNib is slightly different in that it won't be called until everything from the nib has been loaded, but in the case of a cell, that usually makes little difference.

Comment: You just saved my proverbial bacon, Sir :)

Comment: interestingly, the documentation says that initWithStyle will be called when a nib is registered and dequeReuseableCellWithIdentifier is called. That doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: So, in tableview delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath we dont need the if (cell==nil) part?

Comment: @Rocotilos it depends which dequeue method you use. If you use the one with the indexpath parameter, then it will crash if no cell has been registered, so you'll never get a nil cell. If you use the other one, it's designed for you to create a new cell if one hasn't been dequeued.

Answer (score 12):

With the storyboard involved, everything changes. This is the method that gets called.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;

    // Your code goes here!

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using StoryBoarsd then UITableViewContoller won't call initWithStyle replace it with initWithCoder it will works now