# UIImageViews in UITableViewCells are recreating themselves in cached cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uitableview

I've got a `UITableViewCell` and I need to randomly put interstitial images into some of them. This is working, but due to the caching of the cells, the images are repeating themselves further down the table. Let's say I've pre-decided to put images in cells 1, 12, and 25, those cells will have their images, but after cell 1, cells 4, 8, etc. might also contain that first image.

I'm guessing what I need to do is specifically tell `cellForRowAtIndexPath` clear the cache and remove any images if it doesn't meet the criteria to add an image. How would I go about doing that? I've already tried an `else` on the if statement that makes the decision and assigns the image. In that `else`, I've tried setting the `UIImageView`'s image to `nil`, but that hasn't made any difference.

Is there any other way I can clear the cache to prevent these images from spamming their way down the page at regular intervals? Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, and the lines currently in that last `else` aren't having an effect on the images, so they'll (I think) need replacing with something that works!

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    // Make and allocate the cell if necessary.
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"Cell"];
    }
    cell.lineLabel.text = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] line];
    cell.actorLabel.text = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] actor];
    [cell.lineLabel sizeToFitMultipleLines];

    // Get the size each label needs to be when constrained to set width and very long height (8000).
    CGSize labelSize = [cell.lineLabel.text sizeWithFont: cell.lineLabel.font constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(265, 8000)];

    if ([[cellsToContainInterstitialImages allKeys] containsObject: [thisLine.lineID stringValue]]) {

        UIImageView *interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        NSNumber *cellTypeNumber = [cellsToContainInterstitialImages valueForKey: [thisLine.lineID stringValue]];
        kInterstitialCellType cellType = [cellTypeNumber intValue];

        if (cellType == kInterstitialCellTypeFirst) {
            interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"man.png"]];
        }
        else if (cellType == kInterstitialCellTypeSecond) {
            interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"woman.png"]];
        }
        else {
            interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"child.png"]];
        }

        [interstitialImage setFrame: CGRectMake(10, cell.lineLabel.frame.size.height + cell.actorLabel.frame.size.height + 10, 150, 150)];
        [cell addSubview: interstitialImage];
    } else {
        UIImageView *interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [interstitialImage setImage: nil];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` branch of your code does not add the `interstitialImage` image to the cell. You should change your code to add the `UIImageView` in the constructor of the cell, so that in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'd have to set the image, rather than adding subviews.

Add the `UIImageView` to your `CustomCell`, make it private, and provide a property for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIImageView *_interstitialImage;
}
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIImageView *interstitialImage;
@end

@implementation CustomCell 
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle) style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseId {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseId]) {
        _interstitialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
         [_interstitialImage setImage: nil];
         [_interstitialImage setFrame: CGRectMake(10, cell.lineLabel.frame.size.height + cell.actorLabel.frame.size.height + 10, 150, 150)];
         [cell addSubview: _interstitialImage];
    }
    return self;
}
-(UIImageView*)interstitialImage {
    return _interstitialImage;
}
@end
```

Now your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would use `cell.interstitialImage` instead of allocating the new `UIImageView` all the time. This would avoid adding the image multiple times:

```
if ([[cellsToContainInterstitialImages allKeys] containsObject: [thisLine.lineID stringValue]]) {
    NSNumber *cellTypeNumber = [cellsToContainInterstitialImages valueForKey: [thisLine.lineID stringValue]];
    kInterstitialCellType cellType = [cellTypeNumber intValue];

    if (cellType == kInterstitialCellTypeFirst) {
        [cell.interstitialImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"man.png"]];
    } else if (cellType == kInterstitialCellTypeSecond) {
        [cell.interstitialImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"woman.png"]];
    } else {
        [cell.interstitialImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"child.png"]];
    }
} else {
    [cell.interstitialImage setImage: nil];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Isn't my `UIImageView` already being added in the constructor? Is that a separate method, outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Could you clarify the answer slightly?

Comment: I'm getting a `Duplicate interface declaration` error if I try to add the private `@interface` section. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @lukech The example shows what you can do in the actual declaration of your custom cell (keep your other methods, of course). You can also do a class extension if you'd like, but that's a matter of taste. If you'd like to go the extension route, replace `@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell` with `@interface CustomCell ()`.

Comment: Okay, I've done as you've suggested, but now the images aren't displaying at all.

Comment: @lukech You may want to move the resizing line from the initializer to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then, because `label` may not be ready in the init method.

Comment: Yup, already did that I'm afraid, still no sign of the images. It looks like the image is `nil` after the `if` statement, so something isn't being initialized somewhere I guess?

Comment: @lukech That's odd, because you call it yourself on the `cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"Cell"];` line.

Comment: Nope, the `else`  branch isn't always taken, the problem is definitely that `initWithStyle` isn't being called. Which is really confusing since I can literally see it being called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :)

Comment: It looks like `cell == nil` never evaluates to true. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it because I have a prototype cell in my storyboard?

Comment: @lukech Yes, exactly - here is an answer to what's going on: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8522456/335858).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for sticking with me there, all's working perfectly now! :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution should be to use [– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) method of `UITableViewDelegate` Protocol. Clean your cells in this method.

Comment: But how would I know which cell I wanted to leave the image in, and which I'd want to remove it from, from there? I can't just clean every cell, else that'd remove the images from the cells they're supposed to be in, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you know in which cells your images should be you can use the indexPath parameter to track them and clean the cells that need to be.

Comment: How is using `willDisplayCell...` any easier than getting the images correct in `cellForRow...`?

Comment: I think this solution would have worked, but it would've been a stop-gap solution. Putting the image into the custom class was the right way forward.

Comment: By reseting your cell to an appropriate/inial state in willDisplayCell you can get a simpler/systematic code in cellForRow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `if` part you add an image view. This means as cells are reused you  keep adding more and more images views.

In the `else` part you create an dummy image view and set its image to `nil`. This code does not do what you intended - to clear any existing image.

What you need to do is to ensure you never add a second image view to a cell. And when you need to clear the image, you get a reference to the existing image view, not create a new one.