# UITableViewCell subtitle. Not getting it to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Using Xcode 4.6, I am trying to display a typical UITableView with its cells with subtitles.

If I am not wrong, the code is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Test *myTest = [self listTests][indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [myTest name];

UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;

UIFont *detailFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
NSMutableString *detailText = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myTest numQuestions]];
[detailText appendString:@" preguntas."];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
cell.detailTextLabel.font = detailFont;

return cell;
```

}

For some reason, it never passes through this line of code:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

so the cell is never initialized with `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

It is somehow getting ALWAYS FROM THE BEGINING a valid cell when doing `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

What can I be doing wrong?

It is really weard. I always use this code and it normally works. What else can I be doing wrong somewhere else?

Comment: are you using custom cells in IB ?

Comment: are you usng storyboards and prototype cells?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens when your cell is defined using a storyboard prototype. In this case the reusable cells are pre-created using the `initWithCoder:` method, so `if (cell == nil)` never gets hit. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522456/335858) for more information.

Since it appears that you would like to use a cell with a standard style, changing the table to *not* use a storyboard prototype or setting the prototype to "Subtitle" should fix this problem.

Comment: if thats the case, why not just set the prototype cell in SB to "Subtitle"? Saves you some hassle...

Comment: @katzenhut That would work too :) Thanks, I edited the answer to mention that. Thanks!