# Subtitle not appearing UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to app designing and Objective-C. I am writing a simple food app that has some food stored in an array with details of the food, food name, cook time and the file name which leads to a picture.

I am trying to get a subtitle to work but it isn't showing up. I've read various other posts and have tried to implement some of the answers but none have worked.

This is my code if there is anything obviously incorrect please let me know. Thank you.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FoodCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Food *current = [foodArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [cell.textLabel setText:[current name]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@[current cookTime]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[current fileName]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check the cell for nil anymore because the new dequeue method will always return a cell if your identifier exists in the UITableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@[current cookTime]];
```

with

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[current cookTime]];
```

Note that this assumes `cookTime` is an `NSString`. If it is something else, like an integer representing minutes, you would do something like this:

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", [current cookTime]]];
```

Additionally, you may find it easier to use this format:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", [current cookTime]];
```

Comment: Yes sorry when i copied that line in it was wrong with the "@" character before the [current cookTime] part. Cook time is a string so this line [cell detailTextLabel] setText:[current cookTime]]; should work. But still it is not giving me what I want. The subtitle does not appear.

Comment: What do you see in the console if you add `NSLog([current cookTime]);` right before that line? Is it showing what you expect?

Comment: Did you create a prototype cell in Interface Builder? If so, the `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` line is never getting called. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522456/initwithstylereuseidentifier-not-called for more information.

Comment: I did create a prototype cell in the interface which is another reason it does not make sense as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Just a guess. Try to set the style of the UITableViewCell to Subtitle in Interface Builder. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Supplying the forIndexPath argument guarantees that a non-nil cell is returned if the identifier exists. Here is what it says in the UITableView header file: 

- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [current cookTime];
```