# Custom UITableViewCell initializer gets error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using custom cell like that:

```
PropertyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and it's registered as:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PropertyCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PropertyCell"];
```

Class is declared as:

```
@interface PropertyCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

It contains a UITextField in xib and I need to assign a delegate to it on init.

Problem is that:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

is never called in that scenario.

Which kind of initializer is used by that dequeueing mechanism ?

Comment: do your cell is not nil? Do you call `initWithStyle:` when cell is nil?

Comment: No.- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  never returns nil;

Comment: This may be what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522456/initwithstylereuseidentifier-not-called

Comment: Glad I could help.  Can I post this as an answer for you to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use initWithCoder or awakeFromNib as posted in this question...

[initwithstyle:reuseIdentifier: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522456/initwithstylereuseidentifier-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to init your cell in the `UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *PropertyCellIdentifier = @"PropertyCell";
    PropertyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: PropertyCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PropertyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: PropertyCellIdentifier];
    }

    // configure cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is why I'm using: - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath - which always creates a cell if that doesn't exist. Newer method. But I don't know which initialized it is using.